# Comparing two linear models

Tags: r

I am creating a linear regression and then looking for non-significant predictors. Based on what I find, I am trying to create a second model with only significant predictors.  It seemed to me as though I should drop `Arbys` and `vit_a` in the second model.  Is this correct, or have I interpreted the summary of the first model incorrectly?  I am also confused as to why `Arbys` does not appear in the first model summary at all. Dataset is `fastfood` from `openintro`.

```
rest5060<-fastfood%>%
filter(restaurant=="Mcdonalds"|restaurant=="Arbys"|restaurant=="Sonic")
lreg<-lm(total_fat~cholesterol+total_carb+vit_a+restaurant,data=rest5060)
summary(lreg)

new_model<-fastfood%>%
  filter(restaurant=="Mcdonalds"|restaurant=="Sonic")
food.lm<-lm(total_fat~cholesterol+total_carb+restaurant,data=new_model)
```

Comment: include the summaries from your models here, this will allow us to compare them meaningfully. Use the most verbose summary you can get, because all of the metrics matter in different ways!

Comment: Your models are not nested, because they are based on different datasets. Therefore the logic of retaining only terms that are significant in both models is dubious. Also, note that `Arbys` Is a *level* of the term `restaurant`, not a term itself. I feel you should seek advice from an appropriately qualified statistician before proceeding.

Comment: I second the last advice given above by Limey.

Answer (score 0):

As to why Arby's isn't showing up as a predictor, it is probably because R is setting it as the baseline (Arby's comes first alphabetically), then the other restaurants show the difference of having them as predictors compared to Arby's. You can search for more information on this topic under "treatment contrasts."
You can get the coefficients, along with statistics for each with `coef(summary(lreg))`